# creating a xml layout from a custom layout. is it possible?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        setContentView(new SampleView(this));
    }
}
```

**SampleView.java:**

```
public class SampleView extends View {

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (certaincondition = true) {
            //add elements to canvas etc
        } else {
            //How do I do the below? The layout is defined in xml. 
            //I do not want to use Intent. Please help me

            //create a layout from resource R.layout.idAbout and transfer control.
         } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a layout inflater:

```
View newRootViewElement;
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
newRootViewElement= li.inflate(R.layout.idAbout, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate a layout using

```
View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.idAbout, viewParent);
```

where `viewParent` is a `ViewParent` that will be the parent of the inflated view (and can be `null`).

But what are you trying to do? It's more than a little odd to start a new activity or to modify the view hierarchy from within `onDraw()`. You might want to post a runnable to a `Handler` that will do what you want on the next cycle of the event loop. To start a new activity (such as displaying “About” info for the app) you should take a look at the `Intent` class.

Comment: The actual problem is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926478/why-does-the-menu-button-in-the-emulator-show-all-the-activities-of-my-app.   Because i could not fix it: as a work around, i am trying to use a the same activity for all my views.

Comment: The original problem which caused me to use multiple views for same activity is resolved now. Thank you.