# why does the menu button in the emulator show all the activities of my app?

Tags: android, menu, android-activity, emulation

i just want it to show only one activity on the main menu and hide the remaining ones.

My manifest file looks something like this.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainAct" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".StartGame" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Instructions" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".About" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to repeat these lines for all activities;

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Just for the main one

(as an ad-on to your comments question:

From: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

> The icon and label set for an intent
>   filter are used to represent a
>   component whenever the component is
>   presented to the user as fulfilling
>   the function advertised by the filter.
>   For example, a filter with
>   "android.intent.action.MAIN" and
>   "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
>   settings advertises an activity as one
>   that initiates an application — that
>   is, as one that should be displayed in
>   the application launcher. The icon and
>   label set in the filter are therefore
>   the ones displayed in the launcher.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it. btw could you please tell me what are these tags for?

Comment: You filter on an action and a category. These two are the ones that do exactly one thing: the thing you wanted to avoid, being it shows up as a 'main' activity :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is just a guess, but you have 2 intent filters in your manifest. If you only want one Activity for your entry point, you should only need the one intent filter for MAIN and LAUNCHER.